# XNA Framework - uninstaller

Tags: frameworks, xna, installation, uninstallation

I am new to the xna framework. If i publish my game, an installer is created which can be installed on other pcs which is great. But my problem is, that, if the game is installed, there is no uninstaller for that game. What do I have to do, to add an uninstaller there?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the installer you're referring to is a Visual Studio installer project.  If so, your application should appear in the Add/Remove Programs menu, and can be uninstalled from there.

Comment: I want my application to have an uninstaller itself. I don't want my users to remove it through the programs menu, not everyone knows about that.